# How to get request and response information as a post request in Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am new to Jersey and I have some questions about the jersey filter. I try to get some request information and response using a filter.

The first question is in the request filter. For example, 
"requestContext.getHeaders()" will get the request header information. But I only want to get the request-id. How can I get the specific value in header information?

The second questions is : any class or method that can get the request information(for example userid, timestamp, sessionid) and response JSON data together as a JSON POST request?

I get stuck on this problem and I really appreciate if anyone can help me to figure this out.

```
public class auditService implements ContainerRequestFilter, 
ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, 
 ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {


      Object object = responseContext.getEntity();

   }


@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

  Date requestDate = new Date();
  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  sb.append("-timestamp:  ").append(simpleDateFormat.format(requestDate));
  sb.append("-path:  ").append(requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath());
  sb.append("-user  ").append(requestContext.getSecurityContext().getUserPrincipal());
  sb.append("-header  ").append(requestContext.getHeaders());
  sb.append("-entity  ").append(requestContext.getEntityStream());

  System.out.println("the request:" + sb.toString());
    } 
 }
```

Edit: I get the specific value using @Context HttpServletResquest.

Comment: Why don't you just use the [Jersey logging feature](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/logging_chapter.html)? You can get most of this information using this.

Comment: I just need the log information as a post request to another rest endpoint.